# NestJS hashing password

Tags: javascript, hash, passwords, nestjs

I'm trying to hash password in user entity file, I copied code from another project, that code works on that project, but on this one, it doesn't.

In entity:

```
 @Column()
 password: string;

  @BeforeInsert()
  async hashPassword() {
    this.password = 'hashed password';
  }
```

In service:

```
async create(user: DeepPartial<User>) {
    const newUser = this.userRepository.create(user);
    return this.userRepository.save(newUser);
  }
```

It creates a user, but password is not hashed.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Sequelize ORM, the way I did this was to go back to my database provider and add it after I initialize the Sequelize models.

```
    export const databaseProviders = [
    {
        provide: ioc.sequelizeProvider,
        useFactory: async () => {
            const sequelize = new Sequelize({
                dialect: 'mysql',
                host: databaseConstants.host,
                port: databaseConstants.port,
                username: databaseConstants.username,
                password: databaseConstants.password,
                database: databaseConstants.database,
            });
            sequelize.addModels([Profile]);
            await sequelize.sync();

            Profile.beforeSave((profile, options) => {
                const hashPassword = crypto.createHmac('sha256', profile.password).digest('hex');
                profile.password = hashPassword;
            });

            return sequelize;
        },
    },
];
```

Comment: Please don't use SHA256 for password hashing. There are special hash functions designed for passwords like Bcrypt, Argon2 or PBKDF2. See https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html